# tkinter (python): assign class method to a key

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, move, tkinter-canvas

In my simple code, a red ball is falling down in a straight line (that's working).  When I push the right arrow key, I want the ball to also move in right direction. This is not working, however. What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=500, background='black')
canvas.pack()


class Bird:
    def __init__(self, canvas, coords):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.coords = coords
        self.bird = canvas.create_rectangle(coords, fill='red')

    def gravity(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.bird, 0, 10)
        self.canvas.after(200, self.gravity)

    def moveRight(self, event):
        self.canvas.move(self.bird, 10, 0)
        self.canvas.after(200, self.moveRight)

bird = Bird(canvas, (100, 100, 110, 110))

bird.gravity()

canvas.bind('<Right>', bird.moveRight)

root.mainloop()
```

I have another additional question:

Is it possible to call this "after"-function or a similar function for the whole canvas instead of the two methods separately?

If you see any other flaws with my code plz let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the ball go in the wrong direction? Do you get an error?

Comment: The bird didn't respond to pressing the right arrow key, it was simply falling down. However, I didn't get an error message

Comment: ok, so the problem isn't with the binding _per se_. It's simply one  of focus. The binding to keys only works if the widget with the binding has the keyboard focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must bind the right key to the canvas inside the class, and set the focus on the canvas:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=500, background='black')
canvas.pack()


class Bird:
    def __init__(self, canvas, coords):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.coords = coords
        self.bird = canvas.create_rectangle(coords, fill='red')
        self.canvas.bind('<Right>', self.moveRight)
        self.canvas.focus_set()

    def gravity(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.bird, 0, 10)
        self.canvas.after(200, self.gravity)

    def moveRight(self, event=None):
        self.canvas.move(self.bird, 10, 0)
        self.canvas.after(200, self.moveRight)


bird = Bird(canvas, (100, 100, 110, 110))

bird.gravity()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"You must bind the right key to the canvas inside the class."_ This is not true. It's possible to do the binding outside of the class.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it is possible; I thought that it made more sense here.

Comment: thank you, it is working now! But what do I have to change so that the bird only moves one step to the right when i press the right key (while still moving down)? Right now the results in a diagonal movement...

Comment: Glad I could help. The bird is moving diagonally because gravity is pulling it down (updates the position down every 200 milli seconds); you would have to stop that for the bird to only go sideways. Give it a try (you'll have to clarify the precise behavior you want for the bird), and ask another question if you run into trouble; we'll be happy to help you again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you are binding keyboard events, but the events can only work if the widget with the bindings has the keyboard focus. You can give the canvas the keyboard focus with `focus_set()`:

```
canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=500, background='black')
canvas.focus_set()
```

> Is it possible to call this "after"-function or a similar function for the whole canvas instead of the two methods separately?

Yes. Your binding can call any function you want. If you expect to have more than one object and you want them all to move at the same time, you can move them all from a function.

First, remove the call to `after` from `moveRight`. Next, define a global function that calls `moveRight` for every object. For example:

```
def move_them_all():
    bird1.moveRight()
    bird2.moveRight()
    something_else.moveRight()
    self.canvas.after(1000, move_them_all)
...
canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=500, background='black')
...
canvas.bind('<right>', move_them_all)
```

Comment: ok I think I didn't phrase my question precisely enough, sorry. I want the bird to move the following way: Within each time interval, it is supposed to move downwards the defined distance automatically. When the arrow key is pressed, the bird should additionally move one step to the right. So the thing is, I want both movements to happen in the same time interval, if you know what I mean....

Comment: @Kubi: all of that is possible.